# Why is my JSON.parse failing? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, flickr, open-uri

I'm trying to load images from Flickr's API into a Ruby on Rails app, but I'm getting "Unexpected Token" on my JSON.parse() line.

I found another response here where the returned JSON had it's double quotes escaped out, and the solution was to add the .gsub thing to the end, but I'm still getting an error.

Anyone know what the problem is?

```
def add

@jsonresults = open("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.interestingness.getList&api_key=bb398c11934abb6d51bdd720020f6a4a&per_page=1&page=1&format=json&nojsoncallback=1").read
@images = JSON.parse(@jsonresults.to_json.gsub('\"', '"'))

end
```

The error:

```
JSON::ParserError in ImagesController#add

757: unexpected token at '"{"photos":{"page":1, "pages":500, "perpage":1, "total":500, "photo":[{"id":"8234011021", "owner":"24066605@N07", "secret":"b4c05df8c5", "server":"8341", "farm":9, "title":"Crescent Lake", "ispublic":1, "isfriend":0, "isfamily":0}]}, "stat":"ok"}"'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The json returned by the call looks fine.  Change your parsing to this:

```
@images = JSON.parse(@jsonresults)
```

Answer (score 1):

[That is not valid JSON.](http://jsonlint.com/) The outer set of double-quotes do not belong. This is the valid version:

```
'{"photos":{"page":1, "pages":500, "perpage":1, "total":500, "photo":[{"id":"8234011021", "owner":"24066605@N07", "secret":"b4c05df8c5", "server":"8341", "farm":9, "title":"Crescent Lake", "ispublic":1, "isfriend":0, "isfamily":0}]}, "stat":"ok"}'
```

Comment: so I can use .chop to remove the final double-quote.... advice on how to get rid of the first one?

Comment: [John Naegle's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13673841/139010) solves the problem. Like he said, the JSON returned by the call looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Doh.  It sure did. Don't know why I tried to over complicate the matter.

Comment: `@json_results.chop.reverse.chop.reverse`